# WS02 Minimized Deployment for GW Worker node

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I would like to run WSO2 on two hosts, one serves as manager and the other as gateway worker.

I consulted the clustering guide and product profiles documentation, and I understand that after configuring the two hosts correctly, I can run the product with selected profile:

- -Dprofile=gateway-manager on the manager node
- -Dprofile=gateway-worker on the gateway worker node

In addition to perform selective-run, I would also like the gateway-worker to have the minimal possible deployment, i.e. to be installed only with artifacts it really needs.

Three options I can think of, from best to worst:

1. Download a minimized deployment package - in case there is one? In the site I saw only complete package which contains artifacts of all the components. Are there other download options which contain selective artifacts per profile?
2. Download the complete package and then remove the artifacts which are not necessary for gateway-worker (how do I know which files/directories to remove?)
3. Download the source from github and run a selective build? (which components should I build and how do I package them for deployment)?

Answer (score 0):

There are no separate product packs for each profiles to download. So option 1 is not there. But you can do the option 2 to some extent. You can remove the publisher, store and admin-dashboard application from the product by removing 'jaggeryapps' folder in 'wso2am-1.10.0/repository/deployment/server/' location. Other than that we are not recommending to remove any components from the pack.

You can check the profile generation code for API Manager 1.10 in [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/tree/master/features/categories). It only has module import definitions. These component are needed to be there for each profile.